# How to force Android application to reload the activity title corresponding to the language change?

Tags: android, android-manifest, multilingual, android-titlebar

How could force android application to reload activity title when the language of the application has been changed? For your information, the application reloads the title only when the device is rotated. Yet, the content of the activity is reload with the appropriate language content with no problem, but the activity title!

In AndroidManifest.xml file, android:configChanges="locale" has been added with no success.

```
<activity
    android:name=".layout.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Even overriding onConfigurationChanged event does not work,

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // refresh your views here
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    this.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html. check this

Comment: Try setting the title in onResume()

Answer (score 9):

Same problem, solved by forcing ActionBar label reload in Activity `onCreate` method:

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            ActivityInfo ai = pm.getActivityInfo(this.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES|PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            if (ai.labelRes != 0) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(ai.labelRes);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.stacktrace();
        }
```

Comment: What if I am in `PreferenceFragment`, how to refresh the Actionbar and other activity actionbar when backpress? thank

Answer (score 1):

you need to add translations for your title in the app and then the application will change your title automatically based on the user device language... here is how to add languages folders to your app [How to pragmatically switch between different language string resource folders in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018805/how-to-pragmatically-switch-between-different-language-string-resource-folders-i/20020644#20020644)